# How to eliminate the overlapped feature parts which are exposed by Union?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, union

Here is the scenario:

I am performing Union on 2 shapefiles: A & B

A: 300 features B: 8 features.

The result of the union generated is 334. Through the helpful comments I know that it was due to some overlapping features within either shapefile.

So now my question is how to get the union results I want which will simply have 300+8= 308 features.

Comment: Intersect with single input, perhaps you have overlaps in A.

Comment: Sample of your data would help us to help you if you can share some data or create a fake dataset that shows the issue.

Comment: If your shapefile doesn't partition space to be mutually exclusive and exhaustively complete (as if it were an FGDB topology), then a self-Union would expose overlaps.

Comment: You likely have overlaps in your data.  Perhaps multipart geometry, though I haven't tested this.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, got caught up yesterday. Thanks everyone for the reply. @FelixIP it seems very probable now I have overlaps in A. So you mean I shall intersect A with B? Is there anyway to single out the overlapped parts?

Comment: @Vince Thanks a lot. In this case, what I want is to use B to replace the parts in A since B is all the parcels whose land use have changed. What would my workaround be? Use Erase (B as the erase feature) and then Merge?

Comment: @Fezter Apparently I do. But it's quite an ancient file and we have quoted data from it (which is pretty bad I know). I think I will just leave the overlapped parts be and try to work around it. I am thinking Erase + Merge. B as the erase feature of course.

Comment: Self intersect A to find out overlaps

Comment: Please [edit] the question to contain new information. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information

Comment: The question seems to be morphing so can you please [edit] it to make the single thing that you now want to ask clear, please?

Comment: I just edited the question. Do you think it's clear enough now?